# Postgresql read-only user for all new schemas and views

Tags: postgresql

I have database which grows rapidly with new schemas and views every day. Problem is that i need read-only user for all this, without granting new permissions every day. Is there a way to have read-only user for all new schemas and views?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have any answers yet, so I'll be That Guy who answers without knowing definitively. Ideally, one of the many experts here will answer correctly. Until then:

`ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES`
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-alterdefaultprivileges.html

I use this *on* schemas to set defaults for new tables, views and functions, but have never experimented with setting it *for* schemas, which is what you want.

If that doesn't work, Postgres has an interesting-sounding feature I've not had time to try: DDL event triggers. So, you can run code automatically in response to CREATE, GRANT and several other actions. You probably won't need to go this far, but it's a pretty cool tool to be aware of:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/event-trigger-definition.html